# Second condition not evaluating if...else if

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, if-statement, conditional-statements

thanks for the space. I'm currently working in a project where I have to evaluate some conditions. The point is that I have been using this structure during the project, but in this case, the first condition is evaluated and does what it is meant to do, but not the second. Here I attach the piece of Code. Thanks a lot!

```
if (influencerUserId.isCompany === true) {

      recommendedPeople = await Recommended.create({
        recommendedEmail, recommendedFirstName, recommendedLastName, offerId: theOffer, recommendedPhoneNumber,
        recommendedLinkedin, howFoundCandidate,
        candidateInfo: {
          candidateEducation, language, candidateLocation, experiences, similiarExp, ownDescription, motivations, whyFits,
          availability, moneyExpec, currentSituation, otherAspects
        },
        moneyForRec: companyUserMoneyPerRec
      });

      recommendedTimes = await Offers.findByIdAndUpdate(theOffer, {
        $push: { recommendedTimes: recommendedPeople }
      }, { new: true })

      historicRecommendations = recommendedPeople

      let companyUser = await CompanyUser.findByIdAndUpdate(influencerUserId.companyUser, { $inc: { 'companyUserPunctuation': 5 } }, { new: true })
      const updatedUser = await InfluencerUser.findByIdAndUpdate(influencerUserId, { $push: { recommendedPeople: recommendedPeople._id, historicRecommendations: historicRecommendations._id}, companyUser }, { new: true })
      res.status(200).json({ updatedUser })

    } else if(influencerUserId.isCompany === false) {

      recommendedPeople = await Recommended.create({
        recommendedEmail, recommendedFirstName, recommendedLastName, offerId: theOffer,
        whyRec, recommendedPhoneNumber, moneyForRec:influencerUserMoneyperRec
      });

      recommendedTimes = await Offers.findByIdAndUpdate(theOffer, {
        $push: { recommendedTimes: recommendedPeople }
      }, { new: true })

      historicRecommendations = recommendedPeople

      const updatedUser = await InfluencerUser.findByIdAndUpdate(influencerUserId, { $push: { recommendedPeople: recommendedPeople._id, historicRecommendations: historicRecommendations._id, recommendedTimes: recommendedTimes._id} , $inc: {'influencerUserPunctuation': 5 } }, { new: true })
      res.status(200).json({ updatedUser})
    }

In Postman it returns the error I get on the catch 

{
    "error": "An error occurred while sending recommendation"
}
```

Comment: Well then `influencerUserId.isCompany` is likely _neither_ `true` or `false` - did you not _verify_ this? (And if you were _expecting_ this to be only either true or false, then why an elseif in the first place?)

Comment: Likely it is not `false` but **falsy** (empty, null, undefined, zero). You chould just go with `else` and omit the `else if`.

Comment: Hi and thanks for your quick answers! influencerUserId.isCompany is defined in a mongoose schema and can be only true or false! I also tried with else but it did not work as well

Answer (score 0):

Take off the `=== true` and `if(influencerUserId.isCompany === false)` and just do as below;

```
if (influencerUserId.isCompany) {

      recommendedPeople = await Recommended.create({
        recommendedEmail, recommendedFirstName, recommendedLastName, offerId: theOffer, recommendedPhoneNumber,
        recommendedLinkedin, howFoundCandidate,
        candidateInfo: {
          candidateEducation, language, candidateLocation, experiences, similiarExp, ownDescription, motivations, whyFits,
          availability, moneyExpec, currentSituation, otherAspects
        },
        moneyForRec: companyUserMoneyPerRec
      });

      recommendedTimes = await Offers.findByIdAndUpdate(theOffer, {
        $push: { recommendedTimes: recommendedPeople }
      }, { new: true })

      historicRecommendations = recommendedPeople

      let companyUser = await CompanyUser.findByIdAndUpdate(influencerUserId.companyUser, { $inc: { 'companyUserPunctuation': 5 } }, { new: true })
      const updatedUser = await InfluencerUser.findByIdAndUpdate(influencerUserId, { $push: { recommendedPeople: recommendedPeople._id, historicRecommendations: historicRecommendations._id}, companyUser }, { new: true })
      res.status(200).json({ updatedUser })

    } else {

      recommendedPeople = await Recommended.create({
        recommendedEmail, recommendedFirstName, recommendedLastName, offerId: theOffer,
        whyRec, recommendedPhoneNumber, moneyForRec:influencerUserMoneyperRec
      });

      recommendedTimes = await Offers.findByIdAndUpdate(theOffer, {
        $push: { recommendedTimes: recommendedPeople }
      }, { new: true })

      historicRecommendations = recommendedPeople

      const updatedUser = await InfluencerUser.findByIdAndUpdate(influencerUserId, { $push: { recommendedPeople: recommendedPeople._id, historicRecommendations: historicRecommendations._id, recommendedTimes: recommendedTimes._id} , $inc: {'influencerUserPunctuation': 5 } }, { new: true })
      res.status(200).json({ updatedUser})
    }
```

ensure that `influencerUserId.isCompany` is returning a boolean of `true` or `false`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply! I did what you suggested and 'typeof influencerUserId.isCompany' returns a boolean(false) though it stills returns the error and does not do the post.

Comment: Please share the error message you get. You can update it to your question

Comment: seen it. the problem is definitely not because your condition is not working. your condition is just fine. and to be sure, you could put a `console.log("False Statement Runs")` right after the else statement and it should show in your browser console. 

I believe the issue is to do with something you are sending that is not getting sent. You might want to debug every statement in the else block. something might be wrong there. But condition is fine.

Comment: I have tried that way, and the console.log is not printed inside the condition, it's really strange

Comment: lets try to figure out if `influencerUserId.isCompany` is the problem. so lets do something like `if (influencerUserId.isCompany) { console.log("Returned True") } else { console.log("Returned False") }` and comment out all other code. lets see if its the condition or the statements within. I hope am making sense. :/

Comment: I commented everything and just printed a console.log('heelo') but postman did not return anything. I wonder if it's related to somethin else like the route or smtg, At this point I really don't know what the problem is...